# use case statement in where clause conditional

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Using the same query I am trying to list out notices which are not sent. I am closer to query but stuck in how to execute few conditions in where clause based upon certain condition.

I have tried the following query.

```
SELECT 
    vtn.*, 
    vn.v_notice_datetime
FROM 
     v_templates vt 
     JOIN v_template_notices vtn ON (vtn.v_template_id = vt.id) 
    JOIN violations v ON( v.v_template_id = vt.id ) 
    LEFT JOIN vnotices vn ON(vn.vtemplate_notice_id = vtn.id) 
WHERE 
  v.id = 1 
  AND vn.v_notice_datetime IS NULL 
  AND vtn.id > ( 
     SELECT max(vn.vtemplate_notice_id) 
      FROM vnotices vn 
      WHERE vn.vnotice_datetime IS NOT NULL )
```

I want to cocatenate following sql code when **vn.id IS NOT NULL**

```
*AND vtn.id > ( SELECT max(vn.v_template_notice_id) 
FROM v_notices vn WHERE vn.v_notice_datetime IS NOT NULL)*
```

Is CASE statement good option or any alternative? In research found that the CASE statement degrades the performance but I m not sure how to execute conditional statements in PostgreSQL / MySql?

Comment: Do you have MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have two copies of db. One is mysql and another is postgresql. Problem is same for both.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion
You have left join table column involved  in where this work as an inner join  ..
you should move the condition for left joined  table from where to ON condition

```
SELECT 
    vtn.*, 
    vn.v_notice_datetime
FROM v_templates vt 
JOIN v_template_notices vtn ON (vtn.v_template_id = vt.id) 
JOIN violations v ON( v.v_template_id = vt.id ) 
LEFT JOIN vnotices vn ON(vn.vtemplate_notice_id = vtn.id)  AND vn.v_notice_datetime IS NULL 
WHERE v.id = 1 
AND vtn.id > ( 
      SELECT max(vn.vtemplate_notice_id) 
      FROM vnotices vn 
      WHERE vn.vnotice_datetime IS NOT NULL )

;
```

Comment: Did you mean that statement would be like this - LEFT JOIN vnotices vn ON(vn.vtemplate_notice_id = vtn.id AND vn.v_notice_datetime IS NULL ) ... I try as per your suggestion but it won't work.